# Render Object to min Object size

Tags: rendering

I am looking for a solution to render images of an object at a specific size.

I'll try to explain what I want:
When you start a new project, just select the camera and press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>. Now you see the default cube, but with large empty space around it. Now I want to have this cube in an image with a width of 64px, but the cube should fit exactly in the image, with no space to the sides.

Example: I want the image on the right side (for now just the width, but the height should also be set to at least 64px without breaking the aspect ratio)

[image: Right side is the target]

Maybe someone knows how to achieve this? Thanks so far.

Comment: What do you mean, without breaking the aspect ratio? The 16:9 of previous render size on the left (cutting off top and bottom of the cube)? The aspect ratio of the object's width and height (wouldn't that come automatically if you crop the render size in width and height to the cube)?

Comment: i named it wrong. i wanna do tiles. So it need to be 64x64 px, but the object shouldnt be cutted off, but in height or in width it should always touch the sides from the image.